# How to add logging to navigation back or up using navigation architecture component?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am using the navigation component in my Android app, which automatically provides me with back and up navigation. Now I don't want to change any of those behaviours, but I want to add some logging specific to the fragment where the user presses either the up button in the toolbar or the back button.

I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back), and it worked only for the back button, and I didn't figure out how to leave the default navigation behaviour intact. Plus it seems like this adds a callback at the activity level, so it's not specific to the fragment where I add the callback.

And it seems like onOptionsItemSelected is called for normal menu items, but not for the Up button.

How can I handle this consistently without changing the behaviour of my entire app?

Comment: Please check if my answer works as you expected.

Comment: You want to check only the click on the back or up button or could work a more generic detecting the pop on the back stack?

Comment: Are you trying to log the Up and back buttons for one specific Fragment or for all destinations in your graph? What exactly are you logging and why are only back and up (vs all navigation events) something you want to log? Do you need to differentiate between back and up?

Comment: I want to log when a user tries something which opens a new full-screen fragment, and then cancels by popping up the stack, which he can do either by tapping the back button, or the up arrow managed by navigation component. I don't care if it's back or up, it's the pop I'm interested in, But I do care about where in the navigation graph this pop occurs, because I want to log where it happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the answer.
Try this.

Note: This code is copied from my app. Change as per your requirement.

**In Activity:**

In `onCreate()`:

```
// Observe action state live data
activityViewModel.actionStateMutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer { actionState ->
    actionState?.let {
        if (actionState != "NO_ACTION") {
            when (actionState) {
                "NAVIGATE_UP" -> {
                    if (!navController.navigateUp()) {
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            }
            // Reset action state
            activityViewModel.setActionState("NO_ACTION")
        }
    }
})
```

And,

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            navController.currentDestination?.id?.let { currentDestinationId ->
                return when (currentDestinationId) {
                    R.id.fragmentToLog -> {
                        false
                    }
                    else -> {
                        activityViewModel.setActionState("NAVIGATE_UP")
                        true
                    }
                }
            }
            activityViewModel.setActionState("NAVIGATE_UP")
            return true
        }
        else -> {
                item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.fragment_activitymain))
                        || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

In `onViewCreated()`:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    handleNavigateBack()
}
```

And

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            handleNavigateBack()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun handleNavigateBack() {
    // TODO: Add your fragment logs here
    activityViewModel.setActionState("NAVIGATE_UP")
}
```

**Activity ViewModel:**

```
// Action state
var actionStateMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData(NO_ACTION)
    private set

fun setActionState(actionStateValue: String?) =
    actionStateMutableLiveData.postValue(actionStateValue)
```

**Concepts used:**

- MVVM architecture
- Live Data & View model
- Android architecture navigation components

Please comment if anything is not clear.

Comment: All of that, just to detect back navigation?! I don't use a view model on my activity, and I don't want to set all of that up just for this. There's got to be an easier way!

Comment: @Sebastien As I mentioned, this is something I have in my app as I require more control. You can understand how it works and change as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity you should set up NavigationUI first by following code

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_app_id) 
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController)
```

in Fragment you could detect when user click back at toolbar in `onOptionsItemSelected` and then call  `findNavController().navigateUp()`

Comment: I tried adding those lines, even though I already called `toolbar?.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)` in the activity, but I never hit my breakpoint in onOptionsItemSelected in my fragment when I tap the Up button, only when I tap other menu items.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution involves three steps: Define an interface, let the desired fragments implement that interface and override the onSupportNavigateUp / onNavigateUp / onBackPressed method in your hosting activity.

First, define an interface, e.g.:

```
interface CustomNavAction {
   fun logSomeStuff()
}
```

Secondly, add the interface to the desired Fragment, e.g.:

```
class AFragment : Fragment(), CustomNavAction {
  ...
  override fun logSomeStuff() {
    Log.d("TAG", "Up or back")
  }
  ...
}
```

Finally, override the onSupportNavigateUp / onNavigateUp / onBackPressed method in the Activity that hosts the navigation component, find the current fragment and check if it implements the interface. If so, you can call the action. For example:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    // find current fragment, and invoke custom action if up button is pressed
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments[0]
    val currentFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments[0]
    if (currentFragment is CustomNavAction) {
        (currentFragment as CustomNavAction).logSomeStuff()
    }

    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    ... 
    // similar logic as onSupportNavigateUp
}
```

In this way, you don't mess with the overall navigation, and only the fragments implementing the interface will log something.

Comment: I added implementations for onBackPressed, onNavigateUp and onSupportNavigateUp to the host activity, and I set breakpoints there. onBackPressed is called when I press the back button, but neither onNavigateUp not onSupportNavigateUp are called when I press the arrow in the toolbar.

Comment: @Sebastien I've quickly hacked out the solution and put it on github - https://github.com/stefanthaler/stackoverflow_questions_63517369

My two guesses why onNavigateUp/onSupportNavigateUp in your case is not called are: the defaultNavHost property not set / the navhost is not properly registered / a  outdated version of the jetpack (support) library

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not specific to the fragment but in this way, you can detect the back press and navigation up with less code

In Fragment, onCreate add this

```kotlin
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        // enable the callback, when we receive a back press event disable the callback and dispatch the event to the activity
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            this,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    Log.d(
                        "SomeTag",
                        "User pressed up back button to navigate back from fragment."
                    )
                    isEnabled = false
                    requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                }
            })
    }
```

Now, in your activity, you need to override the default `ToolBar#onNavigationOnClickListener()`

```kotlin
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            val currentFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
            Log.d(
                "SomeTag",
                "User pressed up arrow to navigate back from fragment: $currentFragment"
            )
            navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
        }
```